# OneNote Drawing to InkCanvas in UWP

Tags: uwp, onenote, inkcanvas

I want to copy a drawing from OneNote and then paste it into an InkCanvas in my UWP App programmatly.

Currently I'm using StrokeContainer.PasteFromClipboard(new Point(0, 0)) with Data from the OneNote2016 Application.
But is there a way to get the Data from the OneNote StoreApp ? When using the Clipboard I'm just getting unusable data that I can't paste into the InkCanvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OneNote REST API currently doesn't expose any way of retrieving ink information. Do add your vote/opinion on this matter in our uservoice page.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/5657688-ink-support-in-the-api

Comment: +1. Please update uservoice. It's not a great way of sharing our feedback. Can't attach an image or video.